# Common Lisp recursive macro expansion

Tags: macros, common-lisp

Once upon a time I was playing with macros and came up with this:

```
(defmacro my-recursive-fact (n)
  (if (= 0 n) '1
    (let ((m (1- n)))
      `(* ,n (my-recursive-fact ,m)))))
```

And it worked.

```
CL-USER> (my-recursive-fact 5)
120
```

So then I thought it could be a nice way to show students an example of recursion, if I expand this macro using `macroexpand`:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(my-recursive-fact 5))
(* 5 (MY-RECURSIVE-FACT 4))
T
```

That is, no difference between `macroexpand-1` and `macroexpand` in this case. I'm sure that I'm missing some crucial point in understanding `macroexpand`, and HyperSpec says nothing special about recursive macros.

And also I'm still curious to know if there is a way to expand such kind of macro to it's end.

Comment: This seems like an inappropriate example for teaching students about macros. You could remove every apostrophe, comma and backtick in that macro, change it to a function, and it would evaluate exactly the same. (And in fact, you should.) I intend no disrespect, and I understand the desire for a simple example, but showing people asinine macros seems like a quick way not only to muddy their understanding of the concepts but to turn them off to the language as a whole.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MACROEXPAND` takes a *form* and expands it. It does it multiple times until the form is no longer a macro form.

In your example, the top level call to `my-recursive-fact` is a macro form. The result form with the multiplication in front is not a macro form, since `*` is not a macro. It is a function. The form has an argument, which is a macro form. But `MACROEXPAND` does not look at those.

If you want to expand code on all levels, you need to use a *code walker*. Some Lisps have it in the IDE directly accessible, like Lispworks.

Comment: First, I misunderstood the meaning of macro form. HypepSpec explicitly says that it's a form, which first element is a macro name.
Second, it turned out that implementation of my choice - SBCL - has it's own code walker. So What I needed was sb-walker:walk-form facility, which gave me desired output:
(* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 (* 1 1)))))

Answer (score 12):

Slime has a code-walking `slime-macroexpand-all` command: http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Macro_002dexpansion.html

This is probably undocumented and/or unsupported, but maybe you can call it from the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (swank-backend:macroexpand-all '(my-recursive-fact 5))
(* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 (* 1 1)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sb-cltl2:macroexpand-all`

```lisp
CL-USER> (sb-cltl2:macroexpand-all '(my-recursive-fact 5))
(* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 (* 1 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this will break if there is any variable whose name is the same as a macro's in *car* position of a form, in a special operator construct. E.g.:** `(let ((setf 10)) (print setf))`

---

This is pretty old, but if anyone who stumbled upon this question wished there was a somewhat portable way to recursively expand macros:

```
(defun recursive-macroexpand (form)
  (let ((expansion (macroexpand form)))
    (if (and (listp expansion) (not (null expansion)))
      (cons (car expansion) (mapcar #'recursive-macroexpand (cdr expansion)))
      expansion)))
```

E.g. (tested in SBCL and CLISP):

```
(recursive-macroexpand '(my-recursive-fact 5))))

 => (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 (* 1 1)))))
```

An uglier example (the regular `macroexpand` would leave the second `dolist` untouched):

```
(recursive-macroexpand
  '(dolist (x '(0 1))
    (dolist (y '(0 1))
      (format t "decimal: ~a binary: ~a~a~%" (+ (* x 2) (* y 1)) x y))))

 => (block nil
     (let* ((#:list-8386 '(0 1)) (x nil)) nil
      (tagbody #:loop-8387 (if (endp #:list-8386) (go #:end-8388)) (setq x (car #:list-8386))
       (block nil
        (let* ((#:list-8389 '(0 1)) (y nil)) nil
         (tagbody #:loop-8390 (if (endp #:list-8389) (go #:end-8391)) (setq y (car #:list-8389)) (format t "decimal: ~a binary: ~a~a~%" (+ (* x 2) (* y 1)) x y)
          (setq #:list-8389 (cdr #:list-8389)) (go #:loop-8390) #:end-8391 (return-from nil (progn nil)))))
       (setq #:list-8386 (cdr #:list-8386)) (go #:loop-8387) #:end-8388 (return-from nil (progn nil)))))
```

Comment: What happens if you call one of your `dolist` variables something like `incf`, ie the name of a macro?

Comment: @DanRobertson good point. Since we recur on the _result_ of the expansion, that shouldn't be a problem, at least for macros. But special operators that expect a variable in the car position of a form (like `let`) will certainly break. I will edit my answer to address that.

Comment: The thing I was alluding to when I wrote that is that doing this “properly” requires a code walker. And if you get to a macrolet things are even harder.

Comment: @DanRobertson ooh, I get it now... yeah, that was a pretty naïve answer, I’m not very experienced actually

Comment: The problem is that it is actually impossible to answer in portable Common Lisp as you can’t macroexpand through a defmacro which needs `&environment` because such values can’t be constructed